# How to add a label to the Lightning:buttonmenu?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How to add a label to the Lightning:ButtonMenu?i checked in the document it didn't had the label attribute.

Comment: where exactly are you trying to display the label? This can be easily achieved using HTML and CSS. If the label attribute is not available under the component documentation, might as well add your own.

Comment: @glls I want to add the label on the button As you said I can use the label tag before the button tag but i need the label on the button So do you have any way how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the buttonmenu to reflect this functionality.

I would suggest you to use the [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm) component if you need a "tag" within the selection button or you code your custom button.